# Continous daily development with Scala on OSX without IDEs

Tags: macos, scala

How do I continuously compile and run my scala code whenever one of my source files has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sbt tool for this.

```bash
# install sbt with homebrew
brew install sbt

# - create a new scala project
# - name your project name when asked like: hello-world
sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8

# go to the new project directory that you named
cd hello-world

# run sbt to open the sbt shell
sbt

# run your project in continuous running mode
~ run

# to continuously see the test outputs
# open up a new terminal tab, run sbt, and in sbt shell, type:
~ test
```

This will greatly simplify your edit-compile-run cycles.